# git shows a branch "5 ahead 2 behind". I want to keep the commit, but don't care about tracking it

Tags: git

Using sourcetree (and bitbucket), I have renamed `master` to `bustedmaster` (because it's busted) and then renamed another branch (which came from an earlier version of `master` but now has more complete work) to be the new `master`. I pushed the new `master` and bitbucket sees a straight commit path.

However, `bustedmaster` is still tracking `origin/master` from before it was renamed, and thinks that it needs some sync.

It's clearly mistaken. I want it to forget it's old remote tracking. I can't remove the remote tracking because `bustedmaster` doesn't exist on the remote. Attempting to delete the `bustedmaster` branch gives the ominous warning

> "The branch 'bustedmaster' is not fully merged.
>   If you are sure you want to delete it, run 'git branch -D bustedmaster'.

That's not going to delete the commit is it?
Is there a better way to fix it's thinking that I need to push/pull on that branch?

Answer (score 1):

In your repo's `.git/config` you should see a block like this:

```
[branch "bustedmaster"]
    remote = origin
```

You can delete that.